# Click element only if it appears

Tags: python, if-statement, selenium-chromedriver, click

I am trying to bypass a problem in my program which uses selenium and chromedriver. In practice, the program crashes because, for example, 3 times out of 10 ( i use cicle while), a different from the usual one appears. So I thought of adopting the following solution, which unfortunately does not work (so I give you the idea):

```
if WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='example']"))) ==true :

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='example']").click()
else
     break
```

I thought that in that way, only when he found the element and therefore the true condition, he clicked, otherwise the program continues

Answer (score 1):

i usually use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

in a try/except statement to handle this:

```
element_type_to_wait = By.XPATH
wait_until_element = "xpath_example"
time_out=30
element = WebDriverWait(my_web_driver, timeout=timeout).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((element_type_to_wait, wait_until_element))
```

Comment: thanks. That way if the item appears, I can click, otherwise the program continues after 30 seconds in this case, right?

Comment: `while True:
    try:
        element_type_to_wait = By.XPATH
        wait_until_element = "xpath_example"
        time_out=30
        element = WebDriverWait(my_web_driver, timeout=timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((element_type_to_wait, wait_until_element)
        element.click()
        break
    except:
          break`


Is it correct? @Nono London

Comment: yeah and you need to handle the case with the other form so that it break in one way or another